# How to control browser console with a script

Tags: javascript, python, php, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to perform a simple task in a website (like clicking a button).
What I have is a simple JavaScript code, which I can run from the browser console to perform the task. What I need is a way to pass the JavaScript code to the console without physically opening the website, opening the console and pasting the JavaScript code.
I already have an apache server (so I can run php code), what are the options to perform the operation with: javascript/php/python-(selenium maybe)

Comment: run headless chrome with selenium, basic automation

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain? or show an example how to run a simple javascript code with selenium? thanks

Comment: plenty of tutorials online

Comment: @epascarello tutorials I found explains how to do the actions you can do with javascript using selenium.
I just need to run the javascript code with selenium, that what I can't find.

Comment: just pass the js code to driver.execute_script()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selenium, You need to open upa remote driver with HTMLUNITWITHJS

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html

Then yu can simply run the script buy using JSExecutor method i.e.

https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu